# How to pass JAXB marshalled data over sockets

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Am using HTTPServer for my web service. My web server has an object which is converted to XML by using JAXB parser.

How can I send the response using the HTTPExchange object?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
httpExchange.sendResponseHeaders(rCode, 0);
OutputStream outputStream = httpExchange.getResonseBody();
Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
marshaller.marshal(myPojo, outputStream);
outputStream.close();
```

Comment: Its asking me to set response headers first. And to do that I should know the length of my response which I ll not know

Comment: @LPD - I just checked the Javadoc and it says `If the response length parameter is zero, then chunked transfer encoding is used and an arbitrary amount of data may be sent`.  I have updated my answer with the `sendResponseHeader` call.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [getResponseBody()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpExchange.html#getResponseBody%28%29) method to obtain an `OutputStream`. Then use the stream's `write(byte[] b)` method to write to the stream.

```
String strXml = ... ; //your xml
OutputStream stream = exchange.getResponseBody();
stream.write(strXml.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
stream.close();
```

This will write the xml into the server's response using a given encoding, in this case it's `UTF-8`.